# Error en Python: "module 'scipy' has no attribute 'version'"

Tags: python

estoy siguiendo los pasos de un libro llamado: "Aprende Machine Learning en español" por lo que se ve faltan instalar las librerías.
El código es el siguiente:

```
import scipy
print ("scipy: %s" %scipy.__version__)
import numpy
print ("numpy: %s" %numpy.__version__)
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.
```

He hecho servir el comando en la consola de Anaconda: "conda install scipy" y me dice que ya está instalado

En Python me subraya las librerias como scipy y otras.
El problema creo es que no encuentra el modulo. También decir que ayer no me encontraba el archivo: versiones.py.
Tuve que cambiar el archivo de carpeta y ponerlo en la ruta en la que lo estaba buscando.
Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Sin ver el código que has intentado y que te ha dado ese error, va a ser casi imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Hiciste bien en poner el código! Pero no uses capturas de pantalla de código. Es mejor cuando está como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting). Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880